# Unable to connect excel to sql server. Getting an error:

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

sql server microsoft sql: a connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: ssl provider, error: 0 - the certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

I'm using sql server development edition, and this suddenly stopped working.  I think it's certificate based but can't figure out how to specifically fix this problem, despite reading a number of articles.

Comment: What is [this checkbox in the connection dialog of SSMS](https://blog.greglow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/ConnectDialogV2.png) set to?

Comment: Both are checked like the one in your image.

Comment: Someone said that i could delete certificates and they would automatically be created again on startup. Is this a potential solution and if so, which ones could be removed?